# Preventing vs Ignoring Errors with a Try-Catch in Java

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, try-catch, conditional-statements

I have been working on a few projects lately that use a flood fill on a 2D array to create a grid map for a game.

Part of the flood fill algorithm I am using grabs the neighboring "cells" in the grid and floods them if they are an open space and ignores them if they are not.

However, because I am grabbing neighbor cells, I am grabbing items from the array relative to the current cell like this: `grid[y][x-1]`.

Obviously, when `x == 0` an out of bounds error is thrown.  In order to address this I have been using a conditional statement to check that the index I am accessing is in the array. Like this:
`if(x - 1 >= 0){do what I need to that neighbor}`

I know I can also address the error by using a try catch.

However, I am not sure which is the proper solution.

There are a few specific questions I have:

1) Does using the conditional method to prevent an error from occurring, require more overhead and create less efficiency? (I may be flooding thousands of cells)

2) How exactly does the catch block work? Is it conditionally checking for errors in the background some how?

I also made a very small demo code to show you exactly what I am talking about, just scaled down:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare our test array and initialize size 3 
    String [] testArray = new String[3];

    //This is here for one of the methods I have been trying to avoid errors on
    int indexAdjuster = 5;

    //this the index of the array we are adjusting
    int i = 0;

    //now throw an error! uncomment to confirm there is an error if you want
    //testArray[i-indexAdjuster] = "error";
    //testArray[i+indexAdjuster] = "error";

    //IGNORE the error with a try catch
    try{
        //this would result in an out of bounds exception below index 0 (-5 specifically)
        testArray[0-indexAdjuster] = "error";

        //this would result in an out of bounds exception above index 2 (5 specifically)
        testArray[0+indexAdjuster] = "error";

    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("There was an error, but I ignored it");
    }


    //PREVENT an error with a condition test
    //it first checks if the adjusted index is at least 0
    //then it checks if the adjusted index is less than the length of the array
    if(i - indexAdjuster >= 0 && i + indexAdjuster < testArray.length){

        //this would result in an out of bounds exception below index 0 (-5 specifically)
        testArray[0 - indexAdjuster] = "This would be an error, but it is prevented";

        //this would result in an out of bounds exception above index 2 (5 specifically)
        testArray[0 + indexAdjuster] = "This would be an error, but it is prevented";

    }else{

        System.out.println("We just prevented the error");

    }


    System.out.println("Test Complete");

}
```

Comment: For production-ready code, the answer is really both. Always prevent errors/exceptions when possible, and always always always catch any unexpected errors, log/handle them as appropriate, and give the end user a nice message about how everything went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that make a ton of sense. We sometimes know what we are try to prevent, so we can avoid those issues. However, we do not know what we do not know, so we just need to catch those unforseen errors and handle them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, specifically on what you primary focus is: Speed or clean code.

If the error condition occurs rarely and the check is costly, catching an exception may be cheaper than checking beforehand. This conflicts the commonly accepted rule that catch blocks should not be used for regular flow control. Exceptions should be used to catch *unexpected* error conditions, an index outside an array is hardly unexpected.

The test can also be extracted into a separate method, making the code easier to read:

```
static boolean isValidIndex(String[] array, int i) {
    return i >= 0 && i < array.length;
}
```

Or use a resilient access method:

```
static String getIndex(String[] array, int i) {
    return i >= 0 && i < array.length ? array[i] : null;
}
```

(You may want to replace null with a constant value indicating an invalid value).

In your code you can simply use the getIndex() method for whatever index you calculated and act on the *value* it returns instead of the index. Same can be done for assigning to an index, if its appropiate to just ignore attempted assignments to non-existing indices:

```
static void setIndex(String[] array, int i, String value) {
    if (i >= 0 && i < array.length)
        array[i] = value;
}
```

The main issue you face is deciding if an out-of-bounds condition is just a normal case that has a reasonable default handling option or if it represents a real error that warrants *aborting* the method or program.

If its a real error condition, don't prevent it, don't catch it. Let it throw and bubble up the call stack. Whatever caller level initiated the whole action should be the one that responds to the execption. Its important to decide sensibly who is responsible for the handling, a deep-down detail method has often not enough information to make a reasonable decision what an error means - in those cases assign the responsibility to the caller (repeat until the caller *can* make the decision).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. However, I am not sure how to evaluate the practical cost of checking for the error condition. In one of my implementations, I am preforming two checks per cell, on 4 cells, for a total of 8 checks. These 8 checks are performed once for each cell. So on a 10x10 grid, there are 800 checks performed to prevent 40 different error cases. Is that what you mean by the check being costly?

Comment: @MKreegs "Costly" is very hard to quantify and in practice its also a moving target (changes with improvements in the JVM). As boring as it is, *thinking* about how much these index checks cost *now* is a waste of time. You are investing time to decide between two alternatives that are likely less than an order of magnitude apart. Worse, its likely a part of a larger picture where your program spends the little of its time (painting your cells costs likely more than the decision per cell).

Comment: @MKreegs An example of a costly check would be chosing between checking if an ip address is valid by checking its syntax (cheap, takes microseconds) versus actually attempting to open a connection to that address (expensive, takes seconds).

Comment: If its less clear, only actually measuring the alternatives gives an indication. If there is no overwhelmingly clear winner (lets say A takes half the time of B), the clearer code should be preferred. But defer measuring until you're clear that you have an issue that needs to be solved. Proactive optimization is premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Using if statement to check your boundaries cause lots of overhead in each loop iteration.
I suggest you allocate a bigger array by 1 like:

```
String [] testArray = new String[3+1];
```

This cause that you don't need any if condition.
In response to your question about exception handling, it does not run any condition in background. It runs your code and after causing access violation determines you catch clauses.

Comment: I think understand what you are saying. However, in my specific situation, I am using a 2D array that is filled using a nested for loop. If I just expand the array by 1 I need conditional checks not to fill those indexes. I would also need to add 2 extra to the arrays to account for the above and below bounds. I think your solution might work in some situations but not where I am applying this concept.